# Fixed size output data in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to have a matrix which its elements doesn't have the same size .
Say the element_1 = 0.1234567 and the element_2 = 0.1 and I need the element_2 =0.1000000 so that both of them has the same size.

```matlab
clc;clear all

a = rand(4,12);

COL_Names ={'This_is_Colu_No_1','This_is_Colu_No_2','This_is_Colu_No_3','This_is_Colu_No_4','This_is_Colu_No_5','This_is_Colu_No_6','This_is_Colu_No_7','This_is_Colu_No_8','This_is_Colu_No_9','This_is_Colu_No_10','This_is_Colu_No_11','This_is_Colu_No_12'};
rowNames = {'ROW1';'ROW2';'ROW3';'ROW4'};

T = array2table(a,'VariableNames',COL_Names,'RowNames',rowNames);


writetable(T,'Data.txt','Delimiter','\t','WriteRowNames',true);
type Data.txt ;
```

The OutPut is like this

```
Row This_is_Colu_No_1   This_is_Colu_No_2   This_is_Colu_No_3   This_is_Colu_No_4   This_is_Colu_No_5   This_is_Colu_No_6   This_is_Colu_No_7   This_is_Colu_No_8   This_is_Colu_No_9   This_is_Colu_No_10  This_is_Colu_No_11  This_is_Colu_No_12
ROW1    0.139740979774291   0.231035232035157   0.347778782863186   0.279682446566279   0.060995054119542   0.233212699943628   0.507599581908539   0.833087779293817   0.552819386888535   0.43251811668393    0.342580158122272   0.420574544492339
ROW2    0.00459708931895875 0.703626845695885   0.33064632159971    0.85782393462353    0   0.935097755896966   0.582441521353621   0.155241648807001   0.163717355897126   0.48985529896707    0.0134551766978835  0.810989133317225
ROW3    0.791254563282513   0.650747335567064   0.293769172888192   0.15110222627643    0.962791661993452   0.842147123142386   0.586462512126695   0.109349751268813   1   0.00525695361457879 0.700826048054212   0.989915984093474
ROW4    0.513993416249574   0.868158891144176   0.293769172888  0.552496163682282   0.301098948730568   0.779790450269442   0.420527994140777   0.523231514251179   0.0602548802340035  0.261436547849062   0.84923648156472    0.433189006269314
```

Comment: The same size? Do you mean that the numbers are shown on the screen with the same number of digits? I think your real problem is that the numbers don't line up in your text file. You are using TAB characters to separate numbers. Just display the file with the right tabulator size. Most text editors will let you set this size. You can also open the file in Excel, where the table might look nicer.

Comment: I know that I can do it using excel but I need it to do so automatically , not because of the look but for a C code which take a fixed number of characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to do it manually using `fprintf` with [`formatSpec`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html#btf8xsy-1_sep_shared-formatSpec):

```matlab
clc, clear, rng(3);

a = rand(4, 3);
colNames = {'This_is_Colu_No_9', 'This_is_Colu_No_10', 'This_is_Colu_No_11'};
rowNames = {'ROW98'; 'ROW99'; 'ROW100'; 'ROW101'};

formatSpecHead = '%-6s   %-22s   %-22s   %-22s\n';
formatSpecRow = '%-6s   %.20f   %.20f   %.20f\n';

fid = fopen('a.fwf', 'w');
fprintf(fid, formatSpecHead, 'Row', colNames{:}); % write header
for row = 1:size(a, 1)
    fprintf(fid, formatSpecRow, rowNames{row}, a(row, :)); % write row
end
fclose(fid);
```

Then `a.fwf` looks like:

```
Row      This_is_Colu_No_9        This_is_Colu_No_10       This_is_Colu_No_11    
ROW98    0.55079790257457550418   0.89294695434765469777   0.05146720330082987793
ROW99    0.70814782261810482744   0.89629308893343806464   0.44080984365063646813
ROW100   0.29090473891294432729   0.12558531046383625274   0.02987621087856695556
ROW101   0.51082760519766301499   0.20724287813818675907   0.45683322439471107934
```